# Proving Absolute Value Inequality with fractions

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

I have to prove that:

$$\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|} \leq \frac{|a|}{1+|a|} + \frac{|b|}{1+|b|}$$

This is where I am, trying to move from the right hand side to the other:
$$\frac{|a|}{1+|a|} + \frac{|b|}{1+|b|} \geq \frac{|a|}{1+|a|+|a+b|+|b| } + \frac{|b|}{1+|b| + |a+b| + |a|} = \frac{|a|+|b|}{1+|b|+|a+b|+|a|}$$

So basically I want to keep adding to the denomerator so I can make the argument smaller, but I'm stuck.

**Any *hints*?**

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $\frac{x}{1+x}$ is monotone increasing and the fact that $\|\cdot\|$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

Comment: @JackyChong imho you should post this as an answer, perhaps explain what you mean by $\|.\|$

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @user159517, I have posted a short solution.

Suppose $0\leq x \leq y$, then it follows
\begin{align}
x(1+y)=x+xy \leq y+xy = y(1+x)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{1+x} \leq \frac{y}{1+y}.
\end{align}
Since $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$, then it follows from the above monotonicity property
\begin{align}
\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|} \leq&\ \frac{|a|+|b|}{1+|a|+|b|} = \frac{|a|}{1+|a|+|b|} + \frac{|b|}{1+|a|+|b|}\\
\leq&\  \frac{|a|}{1+|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|b|}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If $ab>0$ we need to prove that $\frac{a+b}{1+a+b}\leq\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b}$ for posittives $a$ and $b$, which gives

$2ab+ab(a+b)\geq0$, which is obvious.

If $a\geq0\geq b$ or $b\geq0\geq a$ it's enough to prove that

$\frac{a-b}{1+a-b}\leq\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b}$ for non-negatives $a$ and $b$ such that $a\geq b$, which gives $ab(a-b)+2b+2ab\geq0$.

Done!